# Setting ServerName in apache config

Tags: apache-2.2

I got the following error in my ssl_error_log (Apache 2)

```
[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) 'mydomain.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

It didn't seem to affect anything - my ssl cert (which I bought from Godaddy as a shared cert) works fine. But I wanted to fix it so that my error logs do not get filled with this.

So I added the line

```
ServerName mydomain.com
```

to my apache conf file as this seems to be the CN of my cert. This appears to have stopped the errors. However, all my 301 redirects, etc, point to www.mydomain.com since this is faster and for SEO reasons.
I also added

```
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
```

to VirtualHost *:80

My question is - will having mydomain.com as the ServerName negatively affect anything? My site still appears to work and everything from mydomain.com redirects to www.mydomain.com so it looks like all's good, but I'm wondering if there is something I'm not considering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your ServerName/ServerAlias in *VirtualHost *:443* (VirtualHost *:80 is http not https)

Comment: Thanks deagh! If I put the ServerName globally and the ServerAlias in _VirtualHost *:443_, is there a problem with that?